# Formatting Controls in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, javascript, css, controls, formatting

I feel as though this this is a simple question, but can't find an answer anywhere.  We've got an interface we're trying to move to an ASP.NET control.  It currently looks like:

```
<link rel=""stylesheet"" type=""text/css"" href=""/Layout/CaptchaLayout.css"" />
<script type=""text/javascript"" src=""../../Scripts/vcaptcha_control.js""></script>

<div id="captcha_background">
            <div id="captcha_loading_area">
                <img id="captcha" src="#" alt="" />
            </div>

            <div id="vcaptcha_entry_container">
                <input id="captcha_answer" type="text"/>
                <input id="captcha_challenge" type="hidden"/>
                <input id="captcha_publickey" type="hidden"/>
                <input id="captcha_host" type="hidden"/>
            </div>

            <div id="captcha_logo_container"></div>
        </div>
```

However all the examples I see of ASP.NET controls that allow for basical functionality - i.e.

```
public class MyControl : Panel
{
public MyControl()
{
}

protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
{
ScriptManager.RegisterScript( ... Google script, CSS, etc. ... );


TextBox txt = new TextBox();
txt.ID = "text1";
this.Controls.Add(txt);

CustomValidator vld = new CustomValidator();
vld.ControlToValidate = "text1";
vld.ID = "validator1";
this.Controls.Add(vld);
}
}
```

Don't allow for the detailed layout that we need.  Any suggestions on how I can combine layout and functionality and still have a single ASP control we can drop in to pages?  The ultimate goal is for users of the control to just drop in:

```
<captcha:CaptchaControl ID="CaptchaControl1" 
runat="server"
Server="http://localhost:51947/"
/>
```

and see the working control.

Sorry for the basic nature of this one, any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: And why doesn't that allow for the "detailed layout" you need?

Comment: could you be more specific about "Don't allow for the detailed layout that we need"? You can always add HtmlGenericControl with plain HTML content to the Controls collection if that's what you are after? PS; looking at the example code. I would place the child control creation in the "CreateChildControls" method of your custom control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although you may want to look into user controls, the following page has an example of doing this using a web control. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3257x3ea.aspx The Render() method does the output of the actual HTML for the control.

Comment: Thanks I was able to build a solution off of this article.  Slowly getting the hang of it.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways to do it.  You can make a custom control, or a user control.  I think you will find it easier to do a user control.  It lets you lay out parts of your control  as you would a regular page.  Here is some example documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/26db8ysc(VS.85).aspx

By contrast a custom control typically does all of the rendering in code (as your example you show).  It is harder to make your first control in this way.